# FFmpeg remove negative frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg to work with videos which have a negative start time:

```
$ ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ss 0 out.mp4
...
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2018-01-03 11:35:13
  Duration: 00:00:06.16, start: -1.238906, bitrate: 1425 kb/s
...
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
...
frame=  222 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     166kB time=00:00:07.44 bitrate= 182.9kbits/s
```

Is there any way to cut the video at time 0? i.e. the output should have duration 6.16 and not 7.74. I've tried setting `-avoid_negative_ts` to all the different values. Obviously, I could manually read the negative value and run it again with the correct offset using `-ss`, but I'm looking for an automatic solution.

Comment: Notionally, `seek_timestamp` should work i.e. `ffmpeg -seek_timestamp 1 -ss 0 -i test.mp4 out.mp4`

Comment: If you provide an example video, I can help you resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, `-ss` as an input option works as a relative offset from start of file. Since your start time is negative and will be unknown in advance, you can enable `seek_timestamp` to seek to a absolute timestamp value.

```
ffmpeg -seek_timestamp 1 -ss 0 -i test.mp4 out.mp4
```

Comment: Could you explain more why the start time could be changed to negative after transcoding?

Comment: Because maybe the source video was generated by cutting a video, then ffmpeg can only cut on specific times, it cuts at a previous frame and tags the PTS as negative. Should work but several players (incl. Quicktime) still show them as black. See: https://superuser.com/a/554679