# Why does the -to option sometimes behave differently?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

Two different videos are giving me troubles when coming up with code to cut them 
at a given time, because the same code does not clip the videos in the same way when processed through the same `ffmpeg` command

With the first video, if I specify a `-to` of 10, it'll cut at one frame before.

With the second video, if I specify a `-to` of 10, it'll cut **on** that frame.

From reading a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854406/precise-seeking-with-ffmpeg), one person says "seeking is not always performed on dts, it actually depends on the container. If the container timestamps are pts, seeking is in pts; if container timestamps are dts, seeking is in dts."

**What can I do to determine how my cuts will operate beforehand?**

Ideally, I'd like to be able to find the information in the output of a `ffprobe` command, and then adjust my logic accordingly

video 1

```
ffprobe -hide_banner steamedHams.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'steamedHams.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-02-17T02:19:35.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:43.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 190 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 116 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 72 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-17T02:19:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
```

video 2

```
ffprobe -hide_banner trailer.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'trailer.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-03-14T22:10:26.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 1.0.7 2017040900
  Duration: 00:00:33.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2778 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2653 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-14T22:10:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 159 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-14T22:10:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : Stereo
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use ffprobe to inspect the frames and packets:

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_packets \
-show_entries packet=pts_time,dts_time -of compact=p=0 input.mp4
```

This will show PTS and DTS of every packet.

The following post may help you [identify the closest keyframe](https://superuser.com/a/554679/48078) before a given timestamp.

Comment: I'm aware of how `-ss` works with keyframes, but my problem is with the `-to` command. How would knowing the PTS and DTS of every packet help me to determine how the `to` command will behave?

Comment: Because the `-to` option will similarly look for the timestamp of every frame when deciding when to stop encoding. You'd have to look at your two examples and see why the PTS or DTS timestamp is selected.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but that's what I was trying to ask: What determines whether the PTS or DTS is selected? What should I be looking for?

Comment: Ah, your original question was how to inspect the video. I thought that you might find some pattern there. It will depend on the packet demuxer, I suppose, with there being dozens (if not more) possibilities as to how that demuxer selects the frame timestamp. I'm not the right person to ask though; an FFmpeg developer who knows the internals might know more.