# How to extract keyframe timestamps from video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, ffmpeg-filters

I want to extract the timestamps of keyframes from a video using ffmpeg. I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/554620/how-to-get-time-stamp-of-closest-keyframe-before-a-given-timestamp-with-ffmpeg) thread that explains pretty much how to do it.

However, it appears that my video does not have the `pkt_pts_time` parameter. Instead, it has a `pkt_dts_time` parameter and I'm wondering if this is the same thing or am I missing something? Do I need to use `pts_time` instead?

For reference, here is the full frame metadata:

```bash
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=0
key_frame=1
pts=131683050
pts_time=1463.145000
pkt_dts=N/A
pkt_dts_time=N/A
best_effort_timestamp=131683050
best_effort_timestamp_time=1463.145000
pkt_duration=3600
pkt_duration_time=0.040000
duration=3600
duration_time=0.040000
pkt_pos=215576461
pkt_size=18186
width=720
height=576
crop_top=0
crop_bottom=0
crop_left=0
crop_right=0
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=16:15
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=431
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
color_range=tv
color_space=bt470bg
color_primaries=bt470bg
color_transfer=bt470bg
chroma_location=left
[/FRAME]
```

This is the command I'm using: `ffprobe -i input.mp4 -select_streams v -skip_frame nokey  -show_frames -show_entries "frame=pkt_pts_time"`.

Comment: `pts_time` is the equivalent for `pkt_pts_time`. There is not much documentation, but I think that in newer versions of FFmpeg [AVFrame::pkt_pts was declared deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/FFmpegInterop/issues/103), so [ffprobe doesn't show 'pkt_pts_time' entries](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-trac/2021-December/060570.html). Note that PTS and DTS are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to some documentation to read more about what these different parameters are? Also, if you post this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I prefer not to post it, because I am not sure about the reason for the change, and it doesn't seem important. PTS can be considered as the time of capturing the frame (more accurate -time of presenting the frame). The DTS is kind of "time counter". Search it in Google, or ask the AI.